# remove text in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe df below:
df:

```
Description      
sociis natoque (penatibus/magnis)
nec dui nunc mattis enim (ut/tellus/elementum)
```

I want to remove (penatibus/magnis) and (ut/tellus/elementum) from the description column

so i used

```
df["Description"] = df["Description"].str.replace("(penatibus/magnis)","")
```

I got this output:

```
Description      
sociis natoque ()
nec dui nunc mattis enim ()
```

What i want is this output:

```
Description      
sociis natoque
nec dui nunc mattis enim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escpae values by `/`:

```
df["Description"] = df["Description"].str.replace(r'\(penatibus/magnis\)', '')
```

Or if need remove parantheses use:

```
df["Description"] = df["Description"].str.replace(r'\(.*\)', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Feasible solution using regex:

```
df['Description'] =  [re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", str(x)) for x in df['Description']]
```

This will remove any contents of `(...)` or `[...]`,  parenthesis included